# Can't get array data of Mongoose/MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose

```
var productSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    user_id:String,
    products:[] 
});
var Products = mongoose.model('Products', productSchema);
...
...
Products.find({},function(err,docs){
   for(var i = 0; i < docs.length; i++){
       var f = docs[i].products;
       console.log(f);                          
   });
```

Finally I can consoled this

> { _id: 8017ced8gf73kk25a8d9839x,
>     user_id: '739265b0dlskca14d8djd1a1',
>     __v: 0,
>     products:
>      [ { color: 'yellow', name: 'A' },
>        { name: 'B', color: 'red' } ] }

But what I want is 'yellow' in Array!! not Array data.
I need to access the data in {}.

```
var f = docs[i].products.color;
```

And I tried this but it makes error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it in javascript you can run a loop through inner products array

```
Products.find({},function(err,docs){
   for(var i = 0; i < docs.length; i++){
       for(var j in docs[i].products){
         if(docs[i].products[j] && docs[i].products[j].color){
            console.log(docs[i].products[j].color)
         }
       }                                
   });
```

Comment: It works but I have another problem. It consoled "Yellow Red

undefined
undefined




hasAtomics





$shift


splice


addToSet
set


indexOf

undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined"

Comment: for getting rid of undefined you can put an if statement, but looks like you might have corrupted data.

Comment: That one could't work...but "for(var j = 0; j < docs.length; j++){" This consoled only ''yellow". I don't know how to get "yellow" and "red"

Comment: I found it. while(j<10000){
                                    var f = found[i].products[j].name;
                                    console.log(f);
                                    j++;
                                }